# smarty-php plugin function

Tags: php, smarty

I a having a little issue creating a smarty function plugin. The code is below.

```
<?php
function smarty_function_selectdate(array $params, Smarty_Template_Instance) {
  //year to start with
  $startdate = 1960;

  //year to end with - this is set to current year. You can change to specific year
  $enddate = date("Y");

  $years = range ($startdate,$enddate);

  //print years
  foreach($years as $year)
  {
    echo "<option value='".$year."'>".$year . "</option>";
  }

}
?>
```

while the PHP code should work, when I put it in my TPL file like below. I get this strange error

```
{selectdate}
```

error

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `'&'' or `"variable (T_VARIABLE)"' in /Users/russellharrower/Sites/ABCcars/plugins/function.selectdate.php on line 2
```

I am wondering how do I fix this, as I don't need to send any $params and every time I go to delete that part of the code, it stuffs up even more.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **Smarty_Template_Instance** use **Smarty_Internal_Template $template**

Instead of echoing the HTML, return it.

```
$returnHTML = '';
// Create HTML for years
foreach($years as $year)
{
   $returnHTML .= '<option value="'.$year.'">'.$year . '</option>';
}
return $returnHTML;
```

You might want to create the entire select statement in the operator, to make it easier to work with.

Comment: Could you give me an example because I changed the Smarty_Template_Instance to use Smarty_Internal_Template and does not work